# HTML site built on Mobirise is not appearing correctly when uploading to NGINX using PuTTY

Tags: html, nginx, putty

A couple weeks ago I started building a site using NGINX but wanted to make it look better. So, I started using Mobirise since I don't have much experience with HTML. I built a site that looks like the image below: [image]

However, when I take the HTML code from notepad and upload it to NGINX using PuTTY, the site looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I'm quite inexperienced with HTML, which is why I went to Mobirise to build the site. Below is the code that I'm using for HTML (unfortunately I don't know where the issue might be so I'm including the whole block of code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
<head>
  <!-- Site made with Mobirise Website Builder v4.12.4, https://mobirise.com -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="generator" content="Mobirise v4.12.4, mobirise.com">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  
  
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400&subset=cyrillic,latin,greek,vietnamese">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/animatecss/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preload" as="style" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">
  
  
  
</head>
<body>
  <section class="mbr-navbar mbr-navbar--freeze mbr-navbar--absolute mbr-navbar--sticky mbr-navbar--auto-collapse mbr-navbar--transparent" id="menu-8" data-rv-view="22">
    <div class="mbr-navbar__section mbr-section">
        <div class="mbr-section__container container">
            <div class="mbr-navbar__container">
                <div class="mbr-navbar__column mbr-navbar__column--s mbr-navbar__brand">
                    <span class="mbr-navbar__brand-link mbr-brand mbr-brand--inline">
                        <span class="mbr-brand__logo"><a href="https://mobirise.com"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="mbr-navbar__brand-img mbr-brand__img" alt="Mobirise"></a></span>
                        <span class="mbr-brand__name"><a class="mbr-brand__name text-white" href="https://mobirise.com">MOBIRISE</a></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-navbar__hamburger mbr-hamburger"><span class="mbr-hamburger__line"></span></div>
                <div class="mbr-navbar__column mbr-navbar__menu">
                    <nav class="mbr-navbar__menu-box mbr-navbar__menu-box--inline-right">
                        <div class="mbr-navbar__column">
                            <ul class="mbr-navbar__items mbr-navbar__items--right float-left mbr-buttons mbr-buttons--freeze mbr-buttons--right btn-decorator mbr-buttons--active mbr-buttons--only-links"><li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-white" href="https://mobirise.com">HOME</a></li><li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-white" href="https://mobirise.com">TOOLS</a></li><li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-white" href="https://mobirise.com">FF RANKINGS<br></a></li> <li class="mbr-navbar__item"><a class="mbr-buttons__link btn text-white" href="https://mobirise.com">POD AFTER TOUCHDOWN<br></a></li></ul>                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="engine"><a href="https://mobirise.info/l">free website templates</a></section><section class="mbr-box mbr-section mbr-section--relative mbr-section--fixed-size mbr-section--full-height mbr-section--bg-adapted mbr-parallax-background" id="header1-6" data-rv-view="18" style="background-image: url(assets/images/mbr-1920x1280.jpg);">
    <div class="mbr-box__magnet mbr-box__magnet--sm-padding mbr-box__magnet--center-left mbr-after-navbar">
        
        <div class="mbr-box__container mbr-section__container container">
            <div class="mbr-box mbr-box--stretched"><div class="mbr-box__magnet mbr-box__magnet--center-left">
                <div class="row"><div class=" col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
                    <div class="mbr-hero animated fadeInUp">
                        <h1 class="mbr-hero__text">FF Evaluator</h1>
                        <p class="mbr-hero__subtext"><strong>Welcome to FF Evaluator, a website created to host a number of fantasy football tools.<br> Click red "+" in the bottom right corner to add a new block. These tools are created to&nbsp;</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mbr-buttons btn-inverse mbr-buttons--left"><a class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-lg btn-danger animated fadeInUp delay" href="https://mobirise.com">DOWNLOAD NOW</a> <a class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-lg btn-default animated fadeInUp delay" href="https://mobirise.com">LEARN MORE</a></div>
                </div></div>
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mbr-arrow mbr-arrow--floating text-center">
            <div class="mbr-section__container container">
                <a class="mbr-arrow__link" href="#features1-5"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="mbr-section mbr-section--relative mbr-section--fixed-size" id="features1-5" data-rv-view="15" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    
    
    <div class="mbr-section__container container mbr-section__container--std-top-padding" style="padding-top: 93px;">
        <div class="mbr-section__row row">
            <div class="mbr-section__col col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--center mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <figure class="mbr-figure"><img src="assets/images/bootstrap.png" class="mbr-figure__img"></figure>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-header mbr-header--reduce mbr-header--center mbr-header--wysiwyg">
                        <h3 class="mbr-header__text">BOOTSTRAP 3</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-article mbr-article--wysiwyg">
                        <p>Bootstrap 3 has been noted as one of the most reliable and proven frameworks and Mobirise has been equipped to develop websites using this framework.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--last" style="padding-bottom: 93px;">
                    <div class="mbr-buttons mbr-buttons--center"><a href="https://mobirise.com" class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-wrap btn-xs-lg btn-default">LEARN MORE</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mbr-section__col col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--center mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <figure class="mbr-figure"><img src="assets/images/responsive.png" class="mbr-figure__img"></figure>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-header mbr-header--reduce mbr-header--center mbr-header--wysiwyg">
                        <h3 class="mbr-header__text">RESPONSIVE</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-article mbr-article--wysiwyg">
                        <p>One of Bootstrap 3's big points is responsiveness and Mobirise makes effective use of this by generating highly responsive website for you.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--last" style="padding-bottom: 93px;">
                    <div class="mbr-buttons mbr-buttons--center"><a href="https://mobirise.com" class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-wrap btn-xs-lg btn-default">LEARN MORE</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="mbr-section__col col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--center mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <figure class="mbr-figure"><img src="assets/images/google-fonts.png" class="mbr-figure__img"></figure>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-header mbr-header--reduce mbr-header--center mbr-header--wysiwyg">
                        <h3 class="mbr-header__text">WEB FONTS</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-article mbr-article--wysiwyg">
                        <p>Google has a highly exhaustive list of fonts compiled into its web font platform and Mobirise makes it easy for you to use them on your website easily and freely.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--last" style="padding-bottom: 93px;">
                    <div class="mbr-buttons mbr-buttons--center"><a href="https://mobirise.com" class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-wrap btn-xs-lg btn-default">LEARN MORE</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="mbr-section__col col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--center mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <figure class="mbr-figure"><img src="assets/images/unlimited-websites.png" class="mbr-figure__img"></figure>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-header mbr-header--reduce mbr-header--center mbr-header--wysiwyg">
                        <h3 class="mbr-header__text">UNLIMITED WEBSITES</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
                    <div class="mbr-article mbr-article--wysiwyg">
                        <p>Mobirise gives you the freedom to develop as many websites as you like given the fact that it is a desktop app.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--last" style="padding-bottom: 93px;">
                    <div class="mbr-buttons mbr-buttons--center"><a href="https://mobirise.com" class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-wrap btn-xs-lg btn-default">LEARN MORE</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


  <script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/jarallax/jarallax.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/mobirise/js/script.js"></script>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Your site is not a single `index.html` file. It consists of a whole bunch of files and folders, and you need to upload all of them to your web server. In other words, you should replicate the whole contents of your `C:\Users\Hoppy\OneDrive\FF Evaluator` folder to your web root on the server. If you don't have FTP access to your server, you can use the [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to do it via SSH/SFTP.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan! Do you have a tutorial on how to do this? Appreciate the help!

Comment: @SamHoppen You want a tutorial on how to upload files to the server? That's funny :) Well, read [this](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_upload) help topic on WinSCP site.

Comment: like I said, not very familiar with this stuff lol. So thanks a ton for the help! I was able to upload the files to the WinSCP site but they still don't seem to be connecting. Is there anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Do you upload files preserving the folders structure? Do you remove that `C:/Users/Hoppy/OneDrive/FF Evaluator/` prefixes you added earlier?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your site is probable not getting the CSS which is stored in the folders with the paths:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400&subset=cyrillic,latin,greek,vietnamese">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/animatecss/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/style.css">
```

Make sure the CSS files exist and the path is correct. That should solve your problem .
Double check the path.

Comment: I tried doing that and added "C:/Users/Hoppy/OneDrive/FF Evaluator/" to the beginning of each of the bottom three lines of code you listed (which is the local file path for where these files are located). Unfortunately, that still didn't work. I did it for all the other lines in the code and still nothing. Is there something I'm missing?